# how to change origin to export a animation

Tags: modeling, animation, armature, export, origin

I play on second life, a game where people can use avastar to make poses,animations ect. I opened blender yesterday to find when i went to export my animation that it was a red box with this

[image]

This works with [reference links][blog] I've tried changing origin of the armature, factory reset of Blender, reapplying the avastar addon but to no luck!

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Click the megaphone icon next to origin in the dope sheet to mute it. I upload anims for SL too and this works for me!

[image]